# Attribute.Add using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to to add add an attribute to certain textboxes in my form. What im doing is when a user focuses on certain fields, I want to put the blur property. Here is the code below. Please let me know when what im doing wrong.

`textbox.Attributes.Add("onfocus()", "blur")`

Comment: Simple blur will not help i guess

Comment: Do you want to blur it or make it read-only? There is a ReadOnly property for ASP.NET textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple WPF example. Clicking the button will blur and unblur two of the textboxes.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="188" Width="373">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="textBoxOne" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,4" Text="TextBoxBase One"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxTwo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,4" Text="TextBoxBase Two"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxThree" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,4" Text="TextBoxBase Three"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxFour" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,4" Text="TextBoxBase Four"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Content="Toggle Blur" Click="ToggleBlur_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

The Code:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private _ToggleBlurOnOff As Boolean = False

    Private Sub ToggleBlur_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        _ToggleBlurOnOff = Not _ToggleBlurOnOff
        If (_ToggleBlurOnOff) Then
            Dim blur As Effects.BlurEffect = New Effects.BlurEffect()
            blur.Radius = 5
            textBoxOne.Effect = blur
            textBoxThree.Effect = blur
        Else
            textBoxOne.Effect = Nothing
            textBoxThree.Effect = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I believe the code you are specifically looking for is:

```
Dim blur As Effects.BlurEffect = New Effects.BlurEffect() 
blur.Radius = 5 
textBoxOne.Effect = blur
```